# Live Performance Checking in Zend Framework

Tags: performance, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to check live performance that is, load on server and how much time is taken by each function in zend framework. There are some blog, are saying that, performance of zend framework 1 is like this and performance of zf2 is like this. How they are measuring ? Is there any tool available to test that performance?

After developing my system, how can I be sure that my zend framework application is on its best performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can measure the overall performance locally using a benchmarking tool like ApacheBench or Siege. These will give you a *requests per second* metric that you can use to measure improvements. Then use a tool like XDebug to profile your application - this will tell you where the bottlenecks are. Fix those problems, benchmark again, and repeat until you're happy.

If you are specifically wanting to measure the performance in production, your best bet is to look at third party services like NewRelic for this (although these will usually cost money).

Answer (score 0):

I will recomend to use Apache Jmeter for load/performance tests and xhprof for profiling the code and find bottlenecks.